# Multiple direction NAT

Tags: cisco, nat

I need help with a NAT configuration on a Cisco router:

Here the diagram:
[image]

Explanation:

Computer1 from network 10.197.56.0 connects to Client1, and it's default GW is Router1, but it needs to connect to host 10.100.2.1 of Client2 so it has a static route to Cisco1 (10.197.56.5) which does a NAT.  Also Cisco1 has a static route 10.100.0.0/16 to 172.19.0.4

And here are the configurations for NAT:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0.1   
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native    
 ip address 10.197.56.5 255.255.255.0    
 ip nat inside     
 ip virtual-reassembly in    
!   
interface FastEthernet0/1    
 ip address 172.19.0.5 255.255.255.0    
 ip nat outside    
 ip virtual-reassembly in    
 duplex auto    
 speed auto     
!    
ip route 10.100.0.0 255.255.0.0 172.19.0.4   
ip route 172.24.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.197.56.5    
access-list 1 permit 10.197.56.0 0.0.0.255     
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/1 overload
```

Up to this point it's OK.

The problems comes with the second need:
Computer3 has a default GW 172.30.56.1 to connect to Client3 to reach production networks, but it also needs to connect to a host 172.24.2.6 (mail server) from Client1. I need to NAT in Cisco1 the from 172.30.56.10 to 10.197.56.5 at the same time that Cisco1 NATs computers from Network1 to Client2.

How may I accomplish this?

UPDATE:

I finally did it with NVI:

here the config:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.1
encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
ip address 10.197.56.5 255.255.255.0
ip nat enable
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.39
encapsulation dot1Q 39
ip address 172.30.56.5 255.255.255.0
ip nat enable
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
ip address 172.19.0.5 255.255.255.0
ip nat enable
duplex auto
speed auto
!

ip nat pool NAT_client2 172.19.0.7 172.19.0.7 netmask 255.255.255.0 add-route
ip nat pool NAT_client1-3 10.197.56.215 10.197.56.215 netmask 255.255.255.0 add-route
ip nat source list client2_NAT pool NAT_client2 overload
ip nat source list NAT_client1-3 pool NAT_client1-3 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.197.56.1
ip route 10.100.0.0 255.255.0.0 172.19.0.4
ip route 172.24.0.0 255.255.0.0 10.197.56.1

!
ip access-list extended client2_NAT
 permit ip 10.197.56.0 0.0.0.255 any
ip access-list extended NAT_client1-3
 permit ip 172.30.56.0 0.0.0.255 172.24.0.0 0.0.255.255
!
```

thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you certain that you need to use NAT?  Why can't these devices use their native addresses?

Comment: then i should route every network from each client and i'm not able to do that.

Comment: Could you apply access lists to limit your clients?  I think that would be simpler than all the NAT.

Comment: I agree with @RonTrunk. I think you are trying to use a screwdriver to drive a nail. This is more of an ACL or firewall problem rather than NAT.

Comment: on client 3 you mean only see network 172.30.56.0/24 not 172. ***31*** .56.0/24

Comment: Stack Exchange encourages users to supply answers to their own questions when they find a solution. Please add your solution as an answer and accept it when you can do so. This can then provide help to other users with similar problems in the future.

Comment: I have to agree with Ron and Ron. This seems like an "over engineered" network done for the wrong reasons. You should really look at simplifying this configuration as it will make it easier to manage and troubleshoot when there are problems. It will also make it easier when you move forward with things like IPv6.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

i just redraw your network in more clear way to define the problem ,
first of all you have 6 network and i mark each one with different color and your CISCO router know about 4 of them only so you need to define the remaining two in blue and dark red colors.the blue one by define the router interface and the dark red one by static route then perform what ever NATing you want on CISCO router

***from my side NAT is not the best practice , but ACL with route mab***

a- CISCO router know about 3 networks by default and by static nating will know about the other 3
b- on the GW of the computer configure extended access list and define the source host and destination host
c- on the GW router configure route map that match this access list and set its next hop as CISCO router

and that will make you achieve your gool easy and  secure way

Comment: But in cisco router, interface 10.197.56.5 i need to configure ip nat inside when comunicating from 10.197.56.0/24 to 10.100.0.0/16 (in this case interface 172.19.0.5 should have ip nat outside). When comunicating from 172.30.56.0/24 to 172.24.0.0/16 the interface 10.197.56.5 should have ip nat outside and the interface 172.30.56.5 should have ip nat inside. So interface 10.197.56.5 should have ip nat outside or inside in function of the nat direction.

Comment: you don't need NAT any where in all this topology even the NAT you already  did . just routing can accomplish all you want (dynamic routing or static) . really you don't need any NAT

Comment: I can't use routing since i can't change it from client's router.

Comment: so simply you have access only on CISCO router but not the other routers